# nginx how return specific json from server as POST body?

Tags: nginx, http-post

I want to use nginx as mock for some external address `ext-address` and to return specific json from localhost as POST body.

What I made in **nginx.conf**.

```
location /ext-address {
    alias /opt/test/response.json;
}
```

But it seems, it doesn't try to return  **response.json**, returns

```
<html><body><h1>404 Not found</h1></body></html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `error_page` statement to return a normal body.

For example:

```
location /ext-address {
    if ($request_method != POST) { return 404; }
    return 405;
    error_page 405 =200 /test/response.json;
}
location = /test/response.json {
    root /opt;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) for details.